# do I need to restart ALL the hadoop daemons whenever I make changes to xml configuration files

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, configuration-files, restart, daemons

Suppose my hadoop cluster is running and I make changes to hdfs-site.xml. 
My question is which services/Daemons need to be restarted in this case?
Similarly which daemons need to be restarted if I make changes to `yarn-site.xml`, `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `allocations.xml`

Or should I restart all daemons in every case mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer to my questions.
Answer is it depends which service configuration properties we are changing.
let's say if we change namenode properties, we need to restart HDFS service.